# How do you re-compile a file in the IntelliJ Erlang plug in?

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

How do you re-compiler and re-load a file on the console and/or running program when using the IntelliJ Erlang plug in?

Answer (score 2):

I personally use active: https://github.com/synrc/active
It listens for changes on the file system and recompiles modules if necessary.